# I want to display characters using form in PlayFrameWork

Tags: play-framework-2.7

Implement form and input in scala.html
Enter characters there
I want to display that character

Comment: Can you share your code here

Comment: Thank you for your comment !(^ ^)
It was solved when I asked a question